# Router in front of Untangle UTM

Tags: routing, openvpn, pfsense, untangle

I want to put a pfSense router in front of my Untangle UTM. There is only one thing I am not too sure about.

If the Untangle box will sit behind another router and run OpenVPN, all I need to do to route traffic to the Untangle through the pfSense is add a static route on the pfSense box and open the port used by OpenVPN right?

Right now the Untangle box is the router.

Comment: Old now, but why would you do this? Untangle can do anything you wanted pfSense to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, not even a route. A port map/forward entry on the pfSense to the Untangle should be all that is needed.

Comment: Really? That simple?

Comment: Yup... Just "poking" the right hole(s) and directing them to the correct inside host.

Comment: Well I finally did the switch, and something went horribly wrong, so this idea was a bust. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: What went wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Untangle was not allowing most traffic through the VPN. No one could login to the AD domain, no email in remote offices, no DNS in remote offices... Yet, get this. I could browse windows shares on the remote server and the remote office could see the main office. So I reverted back to the old way, which was Untangle as the primary router and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Any chance you still have DHCP enabled on the Untangle system? If so, you might consider disabling it and allowing pfSense to take over the management of the local network.

Comment: No I checked that, we use our AD server as the DHCP for network.

Comment: Hmmm... How about possible firewall rules on Untangle, maybe needing "rework" to reflect the reconfiguration/new placement?

Comment: That is what I was thinking but I could not figure it out. I am a member of the Untangle forums and I have a support contract. I will have to use those resources. I am sure I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Openvpn server in pfsense ?

Comment: I did not want to use the pfsense OpenVPN because every so often I hear how they are going to drop it in the future version. I don't want to get commited to something and then have it blow up in my face.

Comment: Okay wasn't aware of that, I haven't read about they are dropping it

Comment: They might not be dropping it, I just read somewhere they may be, Come to think of it that might have been m0n0wall I was thinking of. They had dropped OpenVPN sometime back.

Answer (score 0):

A static route on in the Pfsense for the OpenVPN address pool pointing to you Untangle server will be needed or to activate the "Route VPN traffic that would go through the Bridge".

Just port forwarding will just allow the tunnel to be established but if clients/servers on the other side have Pfsense as there GW they will need the route back. (or Packet filter rule).